# Laplace transform: How to evaluate partial derivative in the denominator of a fraction?

Tags: operators, differentiation, calculus, laplace-transform

I am solving a differential equation using the Laplace transform. However, to evaluate it I need to evaluate some strange terms. Specifically, I have a partial derivative in the denominator of the fraction.

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{K}(s)=\mathcal{L}(\alpha) \frac{1}{s- D \partial^2_{\alpha}}\mathcal{L}(\alpha)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}(\alpha)$ is a function of the variable $\alpha$ which I know. I am a bit stuck on how to evaluate such a term. My first thought was to use some Taylor expansion to bring it to the numerator such as
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{s-D x}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{D}{s^2}x+\frac{D^2}{s^3}x^2+...
\end{equation}
Is this justified?  Or is there another correct way to proceed?

It is important to know that they are operators (superoprators, specifically) so I cannot change their order.

Context: I am solving a non-local-in-time differential equation
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\rho}(t)=\int_0^t\mathcal{K}(t-\tau)\rho(\tau)
\end{equation}
This is the result that appears when one applies the Zwanzig-Nakajima projection operator technique. In my case, the Kernel reads as
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{K}(t)=\mathcal{L}(\alpha)e^{[Q\mathcal{L}(\alpha)+D \partial^2_{\alpha}]t}\mathcal{L}(\alpha)
\end{equation}
To solve it, I use the Laplace transform to get the object in the main text (except for the $Q\mathcal{L}(\alpha)$ term). For more information, you can check https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S003040180901044X

Comment: where does the first equation come from?

Comment: @basics I added some context

Comment: I'd have a try writing the exponential operator as an infinite sum, before transforming in the Laplace domain, $e^{[QL(\alpha)+D\partial_\alpha^2]t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{t^k}{k!} [QL(\alpha)+D\partial_\alpha^2]^k$